# Слайдер в секции с остановкой прокрутки секции

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите как можно сделать подобный эффект слайдера когда в секции прекращается скролинг и не возобновляется пока все слайды не прокручены. Вторая секция по ссылке.

[image: Фото слайдера]

https://readymag.com/iamkorzhavina/AQUATONmain4/2/

Comment: погуглите паралакс

Answer (score 1):

Довольно просто с помощью overflow: scroll можно такое сделать

[пример](https://jsfiddle.net/FrogRider/vdyhbesc/76/)

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: row;

  & .block {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 50%; 
  }

  .first {
    background: red;
  }

  .second {
    overflow: scroll;

    & .sub_block {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
      &:last-of-type {
        background: blue;
      }
    }
  }

  }
```

Не единственный вариант решения этой задачи, но первое что пришло на ум.

Comment: А есть возможность сделать так, чтобы скролл на левом блоке двигал галерею в правом?

Comment: Да, почему же нельзя
https://jsfiddle.net/FrogRider/vdyhbesc/107/